# Android using camera intent and saving image localy

Tags: android

I am currently trying to create a button the opens the camera app, and saves the picture with a specific name and location.

this is used to create the name/directory

```
// create a filename for image to be stored into    
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String Calib_image_File_Name = "Calibration" + "_" + timeStamp + "STOP";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                Calib_image_File_Name,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

And this is my handler

```
public void Take_Image_calib(View view)
{
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
           // ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }



}
```

The issue i have is that after the "STOP" , it adds a 19 digit number afterwards. i don't know why this is happening, advice?

EDIT:

File provider

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Comment: Did you add the FileProvider to the manifest?

Comment: yes, ill add the code to main post

Comment: And you have the camera permission?

Comment: i did not add that, i am using an intent to run the camera app and take the picture. and then i will load the picture by reading it from storage. i do not believe a camera permission is required (its already taking the image and saving it).

Comment: If you access the camera you need a runtime permission, CAMERA is among dangerous permissions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. i don't directly access the camera, i just call an intent to open the default camera app and take a picture and save it.

Comment: Damn...you are right, my bad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the `createTempFile` in its definition it has this line:

```
...new File(tmpDirFile, prefix + tempFileRandom.nextInt() + suffix);
```

which I believe causes the problem. Simply use `new File(...)`:

```
File image = new File(storageDir, Calib_image_File_Name + ".jpg");
```